# Android Opengles Vertex Tweening

Tags: android, opengl-es

I would like to render a book and flip the pages .. so I tried to draw a quad using four vertices , how can I bend the the quad ? is it possible to do vertex teweening ??

Answer (score 1):

[Vertex Buffer Objects](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) and their dynamic drawing method should be helping.